# offset of externalgraphic in openlayers

Tags: openlayers

I have created a point on the layer and have added an external graphics to it.
Now i have moved the external graphics image with X offset and y offset.

Now I want to show a label on center of that image set with external graphics. Currently it is showing at the bottom of the image. For moving the label I have changed X offset and y offset of the label as well with the same value with which i moved the external graphic. But still label do not come in center of the external graphics

Answer (score 0):

Try these style properties: `labelXOffset`and `labelYOffset`

(removed the previous answer)